# How to install python3.7.0?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am running a program on ubuntu that requires python 3.7.0, and I dont know how to install it

I have tried anaconda and created an environment, but it didn't work

I have also tried to install python 3.7.0, but when I do python -V, the version is still the 3.6.2 version.

Comment: The binary is likely `python3.7`

Comment: https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-the-latest-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/

Comment: What do you get when you type python3.7 -v?

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting things happen.
When I install python3.7, and changed it as the default interpreter, the terminal won't open anymore. I had to change the default back to 3.6 to get terminal to open.

Anyway, I was able to create a virtual environment using anaconda and it works fine. Thank you all for you help